# What is space according to quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, general-relativity, quantum-entanglement, space, non-locality

We have a pretty good idea what space is in general relativity, yet the strange fact of non-locality in quantum mechanics tells a different story.

Interestingly enough this non-locality doesn't seem to breach the principles of causality so information still adheres to the cosmic speed limit of general relativity (as far as we know). Yet there seem to be some strange connections throughout the universe that give rise to the phenomenon known as entanglement.

**My question**
What is out current image of space considering this very special characteristic of non-locality in quantum mechanics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quantum mechanics does not answer any questions about space or what it "is". In non-relativistic quantum mechanics, spatial position is just an observable you can measure, nothing more or less. In relativistic quantum field theory, which is where you need to go to make statements about causality and the like, Minkowskian spacetime as in special (not general!) relativity is given as the background on which the (quantum) fields live. [Quantum field theory on general curved backgrounds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_field_theory_in_curved_spacetime), is an area of active research, and a full unification of the viewpoints of general relativity and quantum field theory is the elusive notion of a theory of quantum gravity.

Finally, let me remark that "non-locality" is not a feature of quantum mechanics itself, but of its [interpretations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpretations_of_quantum_mechanics). Bell's theorem tell us that we must either give up locality or realism (although we may choose to give up both), and accordingly there are local and non-realist as well as non-local and realist interpretations of quantum mechanics. So to consider non-locality as a "very special characteristic" of quantum mechanics is an error - the formalism of QM itself does not necessarily imply locality or non-locality either way.